# Where is the definition of the POSIX function "stat" on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, posix, system-calls

On Windows, `stat` and pretty much all other C/POSIX functions Windows supplies are defined in msvcrt.dll, which is the C runtime library.

On Linux, I know a lot of POSIX C functions are system calls. I also know when linking a program, you can't have undefined references. I have searched all `so` files in `/lib` and `/usr/lib` for the symbol `stat` or "mangled/prefixed" form but have not found anything. This is the command I used:

```sh
objdump -T /lib/*.so* /usr/lib/*.so* | grep "stat"
```

It didn't turn up the `stat` I was looking for.

So my question becomes: where is it, and any other "system calls" defined?

Comment: @krynr I think what he wants is the stub code that calls the kernel. My guess is a `.o` file escaped the `.so` search, but I don't have Linux handy.

Comment: @krynr mightily unhelpful. A linker needs to link some library or executable containing the definition or forwarded definition (in the case of an import library).

Comment: @rubenvb: You mean declaration, that's something different. One moment.

Comment: @krynr No, a (non-definition) declaration is what you find in a header file. The compiler does not know how to connect that to the kernel.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might make [linux kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_kernel) [system calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) without even using the `libc` (but this is probably a bad practice). The [Linux Assembly Howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Assembly-HOWTO/) explains (in its chapters 5 & 6) how to do that (on x86 Linux 32 bits at least).

But I think it is a bad idea. Going thru the `libc` is good practice, and might even be faster (because e.g. of [VDSO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VDSO)), and is more portable.

Comment: I know it might seem like it's not really an answer to the question, but it is the answer to the question leading to this question `:)`. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

On my Linux machine, I can find the `stat` (weak) symbol and `__stat` (non-weak) in  `/usr/lib/libc.a`

Comment: Well, now I feel dumb. The list was a lot longer than I imagined `:/`. So I guess there is no way to "dump" `libc` on Linux the way `msvcrt.dll` can be left out on Windows?

Comment: Of course you can dump the `stat` code from the `libc.a` but as @krynr mentioned all the `stat` real code is in the kernel. In the libc you will basically only find the syscall invocation.

Comment: Some more googling points me to the use of `syscall`. Would this be the correct analogue of low-level Windows API function calls?

Answer (score 2):

First of all `stat` is ambiguous; there's a `stat` syscall and there is a function `stat` that can be called from user space which calls the syscall. That last function is (on my system at least) defined in `/usr/include/sys/stat.h` (that's right, it's in the header file). It actually has several definitions (all one liners that call a different function, like e.g. `__fxstat`) of which one is chosen depending on compiler and system and whatnots.

Anyhow, `stat` (and other syscalls) are just wrappers that call the kernel (usually with a lot of orchestration). That is why I was initially confused about what you meant. I hope though, I could help despite my unhelpful first comment.

Comment: The origin of this question is that on Windows I can completely bypass a thing like `stat` and thus `libc`/`msvcrt` and call into `kernel32` directly. I'd like to know if such a thing can "easily"/safely be achieved on Linux.

Comment: @rubenvb: You can use `syscall` or `__SYSCALL`. But it will be platform depended then.

Comment: I did tag this question Linux, didn't I? Or do you mean architecture dependent?

Comment: @rubenvb: Possible is: processor, linux version, 32 or 64bit. Platform depended means, that you use features that only one platform provides, and platform means everything not you program.

Answer (score 1):

You can call it with [syscall(2)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/syscall.2.html)

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
...
syscall(SYS_stat, path, buf);
```

see also Linux syscall reference: http://syscalls.kernelgrok.com/